# MainActivity não encontra o activity_main

Tags: android

Tento chamar os componentes do meu activity_main e ele não acha, oque pode estar errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verifique nos seus import's qual `R` ele está trazendo!

Este que está sendo exibido, pertence ao [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)!

Para que tenha acesso aos layout's do seu projeto, importe o `R` referente ao seu projeto,

```
import seu.pacote.R;
```

Comment: Sim, na verdade ele tinha de encontrar automaticamente, porém eu tive de importar o R manualmente, fiz import android.R;

Comment: Na verdade ele trás a lista de possíveis classes que começam com R. é possível configurar. Fiz um teste aqui: Se digito **R + ctrl + space**, ele trás o do meu pacote em primeiro da lista. Agora se digito digito **R.layo + ctrl + space**, ele trás o do suporte: android.support.design

Comment: Realmente, estava importando o pacote errado, deu certo aqui, obrigado!